# Failed to use "generate" for memory

Tags: verilog, vivado

I'm using Verilog-2001 with Vivado 2015.4. There is my code:

```
parameter SHIFT = 16;

wire                           integrators_reset;
reg [INTEGRATOR_WIDTH - 1 : 0] sum_mem [SHIFT - 1 : 0];
reg [SHIFT - 1 : 0]            full_mem;

wire [SHIFT - 1 : 0]    equal;   

genvar i; 
generate
    for(i = 0; i < SHIFT; i = i + 1) begin
        always @(negedge equal[i]) begin
            if(integrators_reset) begin
                sum_mem[i] <= 0;
                full_mem[i] <= 0;
            end
            else begin
                if(sum_mem[i] == INTEGRATOR_MAX) 
                    full_mem[i] <= 1;
                else 
                    sum_mem[i] <= sum_mem[i] + 1;
            end
        end            
    end
endgenerate
```

There is the error:

```
ERROR: [DRC 23-20] Rule violation (MDRV-1) Multiple Driver Nets- Net sum_mem[0][0] has multiple drivers
```

If i'm not using "generate" all is fine. For example:

```
always @(negedge equal[0]) begin
    if(integrators_reset) begin
        sum_mem[0] <= 0;
        full_mem[0] <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if(sum_mem[0] == INTEGRATOR_MAX) 
            full_mem[0] <= 1;
        else 
            sum_mem[0] <= sum_mem[0] + 1;
    end
end
```

And there is not errors during implementation.

Comment: A suggestion, in your statement, perhaps try adding, if(sum_mem[i]==INTERGRATOR_MAX) begin
   full_mem[i] <= 1;
   sum_mem[i] <= sum_mem[i];
end

My only thought is that by not assigning the value, the tool is assuming an assignment, that is not correct.

Comment: @RichMaes, are you suggesting me assign a value to this value? Why? I need to increment it if value is not MAX.

Comment: @Yahniukov, it is more about that your are not forcing the sum_mem[i] <= sum_mem[i], when you are not incrementing.  In general, it is "Probably" okay, but I like to be definative.  Another way of looking at it is to say, that you don't care what sum_mem[i] does when sum_mem[i] == INTERGRATOR_MAX.   If it is giving you what you want in simulation, then don't worry about it.   But if this was an ASIC, someone would ask in the design review if I didn't care what sum_mem[i] did during all conditions.  Just call it personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a tool limitation. You should be able to assign different fixed elements of an unpacked array from different always blocks. One workaround would be to move the declaration of sum_mem into the generate block.

```
for(I = 0; I < SHIFT; i = i + 1) begin : block_name
        reg [INTEGRATOR_WIDTH - 1 : 0] sum_mem;
        always @(negedge equal[I]) begin 
            if(integrators_reset) begin
                sum_mem <= 0;
                full_mem[i] <= 0;
            end
            else begin
                if(sum_mem[i] == INTEGRATOR_MAX) 
                    full_mem[i] <= 1;
                else 
                    sum_mem <= sum_mem + 1;
            end
        end            
    end
```

Now you have `block_name[0].sum_mem`, `block_name[1].sum_mem`, but you can not access `block_name` with a variable index.

Comment: So, if I understand right, I should choose another way?

Comment: You can put the code for one iteration of the for loop into a module, and then create an array of modules.